# Water inside both bulbs in bathroom fixture

Tags: electrical

I noticed the bathroom light was going dim, so I went to change the bulbs. When I took the glass bowl cover off, water poured out of it . . . and then I saw that both light bulbs had water IN them.
My landlord says they can't look at it til the end of the week, and I am concerned about this. Can I safely remove the bulbs? Do I need to find the breaker and turn that off?

At this time, there is no water dripping from the ceiling or the fixture, but there still is water in both bulbs.

Thank you in advance

Comment: OH CRAP!  How in the heck did water get there in the first place?   And YES, turn off the breaker to that circuit before you do ANYTHING more.   What type of bulbs? There's no way incandescent bulbs could get water inside them, they must be LED....More details please

Comment: Water and electricity is danger danger Will Robertson.  Turn off breaker.  Most bulbs are sealed, so water in them is time to tell landlord to get his bottom there now or face wrongful death suit.

Comment: How much water are we talking? Can you add any pictures?

Comment: Thank you about the breaker - I thought so! I am looking to see how to add photos here. .

Comment: @Machavity does it matter when it concerns water and electricity and person/people when no water should be near there.

Comment: As far as how it got there - flat roof, and lots of rain a while back. No leaks elsewhere though. And one of the bulbs is LED - the other I am not sure about, since I didn't install it and am not electrically savvy. It is a dimmable bulb, and that's about the extent of my knowledge on it.

Comment: Thank you all! I didn't expect such quick answers. Breaker is off . .

Comment: @Annette How it happen is beside the point, needs to be fixed now.  Water can carry electricity, so any water you touch can have power in it, which can be deadly.

Comment: Don't let landlord just dry out fixture.  Make sure he fixes where leak came from and removes/dries ceiling/walls where most water went.  Very unlikely the water in fixture was all there was.

Comment: LED light bulbs are not water tight unless they are specifically rated for outdoor use.

Comment: @Annette -- as to adding photos: hit [edit] at the bottom left of your post, in "share edit...", then use the "mountain and sun" button on the editor toolbar to add your pics

Comment: @crip659 Yes and no. No, a fixture should not accumulate water. Yes, a bathroom fixture could accumulate some minor amounts if you take long, hot showers and it doesn't dry in between. The latter isn't as big a deal so we should rule it out

Comment: I would turn the power off to remove the lamps but after replacement leave the cover off and install an old school incandescent for light until the leak is repaired. (Yes I would use the light unless it is inside a shower or directly over the tub).

Comment: I have once seen an incandescent bulb with water in before- still  worked too. The water had been dripping down the cord.